# How to correspond a list value to another value in another list in python

Tags: python, list, variables, row

My current line of code is shown below:

```
year = [1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016]
intake = [26242.5,27906.7,29192.7,30407.5,1564.9,2313.5,2989.4,3668.6,22082.6,29964.2,30481.6,35981.7,39597.6,38659.6, 34325.9,6913.5,35780.6,39111.5,37116.5,35385.5]
outtake = [14311.4,12135.1,3381.0,2186.8,22732.6,21519.8,19932.3,18903.2,24347.6,3307.0,3261.5,34668.1,43695.2,36286.6,26648.6,34325.9,36913.5,26580.6,27679.5,28643.0]
```

I want to find the 3 lowest values in 'outtake' list and label as variables {val1}, {val2}, {val3} which corresponds with the same row[] in the 'year' list as variables {yr1}, {yr2}, {yr3} respectively.

The desired output shld be a print message:

```
The 3 lowest outtake values are {val1}, {val2}, {val3} at year {yr1}, {yr2}, {yr3} respectively.
```

How should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over two lists at the same time, [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort them (by the first element) and slice notation (`[start:end]`) to get the first three

```
sorted(zip(outtake, year))[:3]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can present those values in a neater way like the desired outcome?